# How to use use REST APIs in Drupal?

Tags: 7, social-network

I will present the problem as an example: If I want to use the twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline

In the link above, under "Example Request", it shows the GET  command also the response.

Two questions:

1. In Drupal - How do I make this GET call from my module file? (do I need Services module?)
2. How to parse and use the output (i.e. save it into variables and show in my form elements/page) that I receive from the GET  command?

Any links/resources or just simply pointing me in the right direction will be very helpful.

Comment: You're most probably wanting to look into drupal_http_request: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of your previous question, just substituting Twitter for Google. If you have further information to add to a question please put it in the original question rather than asking it again and changing a couple of small things. To increase your chances of getting an answer to your original question, I'd strongly advise including details of what you've tried yourself. At the moment it reads like a request for a tutorial, which is off topic and must likely wont be answered. Not having a go or anything, just saying

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the other question. Seemed like i "better" framed it here.
I am not looking for complete tutorials, just a direction to research into. I am looking into Jimajamma's suggestion of drupal_http_request and post back a response if i can crack it.